# Splitting message in to chunks like in SMS and finding message length limit

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to split a message into chunks and also annotate the chunks without cutting any words. These chunks have a character limit associated to them

For example, with char limit 20

input:

```
"Hi there Mr. Programmer!"
```

Output:

```
["Hi there Mr.(1/2)", "Programmer!(2/2)"]
```

I am having trouble figuring out the limit of the message length. There is a limit for the message length because length of the message can cause the chunk to exceed the character limit.

ex:

```
"Hey Bobby! There is a ball in the park today"
```

If I set the character limit to `11`, I start to run into issues where the character limit is't enough.

```
"Hey(1/10)"    9 = 3 + 6
"Bobby(2/10)"  11 = 5 + 6
"!(3/10)"      7
"There(4/10)"  11
"is a(5/10)"   10
"ball(6/10)"   10
"in(7/10)"     8
"the(8/10)"    9
"park(9/10)"   10
"today(10/10)" 12 = 5 + 7 --> over char limit!
```

Comment: For every arbitrary message length, I can name you a German word that would make it impossible to split the text into parts with that logic. You can’t find a number that’s perfect; if you choose a not-too-small number (e.g. the 140 characters in SMS or Twitter), you can produce very good results but there will still be edge cases.

Comment: @poke got it. I was thinking about it a bit more and you're right there probably isnt an ideal number.